# How to insert strings in array while looping in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

How can I insert strings in an array while looping in MATLAB? I know it's very simple but I get a mismatch error. Here is sample code.

```
s={'asd', 'xyzs', 'pqrs','mnopr'};    
for i=1:4
    w=randint(1,1,[1,2]);

    switch w   
      case 1 
        word(i)=s(i);

      otherwise  
        word(i)=3;   
    end   
end
```

Comment: The first line should be `s={'asd', 'xyzs', 'pqrs', 'mnopr'}`, no?

Comment: I tried very hard but I don't understand your question… Can you clarify a little bit?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that *s* is a cell and *word* is not. There are many things you can do to fix this, but an easy way would be to define *word* to be a cell of *size(s)*. You would then have to convert any numbers into cells before inserting them, which means that your code would look like this:

```
s={'asd','xyzs','pqrs','mnopr'};

word = cell(size(s));

for i=1:4

    w=randint(1,1,[1,2]);

    switch w

    case 1:

        word(i)=s(i);

    otherwise

        word(i)= num2cell(3);

    end

end
```